# When do the curves $r=a(1+\sin\theta)$ $r=a(1-\sin\theta)$ intersect?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

By converting the equations to $x$- and $y$-components, and setting them equal, I get they intersect at $\theta=0,\pi$, giving the points $(a,0)$ and $(a,\pi)$. But I don't get the point $(0,0)$--how would I find that?

Comment: Don't start by converting to Cartesian coordinates. Use the polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$. If the two curves intersect, the two values of $r$ are equal. And hence $1 + \sin\theta = 1 - \sin\theta$. Thus...

Comment: @SimonS But how would you equate, equating the two r functions would just give when r is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the third point of intersection happens when $\theta = 3\pi/2, r_1 = 0$  and $\theta = \pi/2, r_2 = 0.$ that is the point $r = 0$ in polar coordinates and $(0,0)$ in cartesian coordinates.

Comment: I know that (0,0) is, but how do i find it, i split each into x and y components, for example for $r= a(1+sin\theta)$ I did this:  $x=a(cos\theta + cos\theta sin\theta)$ and $y=a(sin\theta +sin^2\theta)$.. Then I equated the x and y components of both curves, from that I don't get (0,0)

Comment: @Sean, you are forgetting, it happens a lot when you are working polar coordinates, that $r = 0$ is a singular point.  if you set $r_1 = 0 = r_2$ you find that they have the solution $\theta_1 = 3\pi/2$ and $\theta_2 = \pi/2$

Comment: so basically when Im working with curves around the point (0,0) i should test the point r=0 to see if both go through the point

Comment: @Sean, that is right. in this case, you have two cardioids, symmetric about the $x-axis. they cut at three points.

Answer (score 0):

If you transform to Cartesian coordinates, you get

$$x^2+y^2=a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+ay\\
x^2+y^2=a\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-ay$$

Equating these two equations gives you $x^2=a|x|$, which has three solutions $(0,0),(0,\pm a)$.